# Pygame does not let me open images

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently following a youtube series by Meloonatic Melons. I am trying to create textures for my game tiles. [This is the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDgUWg8IiuQ&t=1s) I am currently watching.

My code spits out an error message saying that pygame could not open the image. I looked online and most of them said to make sure the image file was in the same working directory, so I placed the Python code in the same folder where I stored my images. Some also said to enter the full file path, but that also results in an error.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()

pygame.init()

class Tiles:

    Size = 32

    def  Load_Texture(file, Size):
        bitmap = pygame.image.load(file)
        bitmap = pygame.transform.scale(bitmap, (Size,Size))
        surface = pygame.Surface((Size,Size), pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.SRCALPHA)
        surface.blit(bitmap, (0,0))
        return surface

    print(cwd)
    Grass = Load_Texture("graphics\\grass.png", Size)
```

This is the error that would be spit out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kylem\Desktop\First Python Game\scripts\textures.py", line 7, in <module>
    class Tiles:
  File "C:\Users\kylem\Desktop\First Python Game\scripts\textures.py", line 19, in Tiles
    Grass = Load_Texture("scripts\\grass.png", Size)
  File "C:\Users\kylem\Desktop\First Python Game\scripts\textures.py", line 12, in Load_Texture
    bitmap = pygame.image.load(file)
pygame.error: Couldn't open scripts\grass.png
```

I placed the image and code in the same folder 
and also if I put the full file name like so:

```
Grass = Load_Texture("C:\Users\kylem\Desktop\First Python Game\scripts\grass.png", Size)
```

I get an error pop up that says:

[image: the error pop up]

Comment: Is image uncorrupted? Can you open it with graphic editor?

Comment: Backslashes have special meaning in Python string literals.  Either double them, use a raw string (`r"C:\Users\..."`), or use forward slashes.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue with your code is probably to do with the fact that you used single backslashes when referencing files. Using a single backslash in python it sometimes causes unwanted errors, so this is what I suggest you try:

```
Grass = Load_Texture("C:/Users/kylem/Desktop/First Python Game/scripts/grass.png", Size)
```

If this doesn't work then I think your file is probably corrupt, in which case you should try redownloading it, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I am the creator of the video you are watching! That is a very strange error you are having and I am sure I have had that error before. I can see you have tried printing out the current working directory to see where the program is running from. I do not see anything wrong with your program, so I recommend you try re-installing Python or Pygame.